# What is the best strategy for dealing with Games (HTMLCanvasElement) inside Angular?

Tags: angular, canvas

Most of the work I do is Canvas based in some form. I am new to Angular which I am learning in order to create the "container" for all of these loose experiments.

Generally speaking, all my experiments start with some kind of a root class. For example. The entry point may look like this.

**CarGameApplication.ts**

```
export class CarGameApplication extends PIXI.Application {

    constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {

          super(canvas);

    }

}
```

Then I guess I would want a component for this in Angular.

**car-game.component.ts**

```
export class CarGameComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
   private demo: CarGameApplication;

   constructor(private zone: NgZone){}

   ngAfterViewInit(){

       this.canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
       this.canvas.width = ?;
       this.canvas.height = ?;

       this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
             this.demo = new CarGameApplication(this.canvas)
       });

   }

}
```

**car-game.component.html**

```
 <canvas #canvasRef></canvas>
```

So this is where I am going with this and trying to omit unimportant boilerplate. Here are my questions:

1. I need this canvas to fill the component. Lets ignore resizing, assume it will never resize for this purpose. What properties should I use on an Angular Component to get the width and height of `car-game.component.ts`? I don't want scrolling of any kind.
2. As you can see above, my experiment extends `PIXI.Application`. The details are not important, but, how can I escape angular zone for the entire application? Capturing MouseEvents on the canvas, running requestAnimationFrame and so on. Angular should ignore this. You can see above that I naively attempted to run the whole thing outside of Angular Zone, however, consulting dev tools, each `requestAnimationFrame` ticks with `ZoneTask.invoke`. I don't expect it there and misunderstand.

Would you be able to shine some light on these 2 points? Is there a preferable method or strategy to use when spanning these 2 worlds?

Thanks!